# Laravel modal query

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get array of related model to my data and it returns null.

## Code

```
public function collection()
{
    return Product::with(['allBarcodes' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('serial_number');
      }])->get();
}
```

## result

[image: one]

**Also** I tried pluck like `$query->pluck('serial_number');` and result was

[image: two]

#### My real data

the data I suppose to receive is like

```
[{
  "id":1,
  "product_id":1,
  "serial_number":"5245412185", // I only need this to be return as array
  "sold":1,
  "created_at":"2020-05-24T04:21:56.000000Z",
  "updated_at":"2020-05-24T04:21:56.000000Z"
}]
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: how did you define your relationships in the models ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing this `$query->select('serial_number');` you are only selecting serial_number and not the column that connects both the modals i.e. **product_id** inside barcodes table.

Do this.
`$query->select('product_id', 'serial_number');`. However this will return 2 columns. If you want just one then you will have to use [collection transform](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-transform).

```
$products = $products->map(function ($product) {
    $product->allBarcodes->transform(function ($q) {
        return $q->serial_number;
    });
    return $product;
});
```

Keep me posted in the comments below.

Comment: sorry I'm a bit confused now my code `Product::with(['allBarcodes' => function ($query) {` is inside `public function collection() {...}` now where this `$products->map()` came from?

Comment: Store the result like this `$products = Product::with...` and the use **map()** and then simply **return $products**

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::map()`

Comment: `return Product::with(['allBarcodes'])->map(function ($product) {
            $product->allBarcodes->transform(function ($q) {
                return $q->serial_number;
            });
            return $product;
        })->get();`

Comment: Do `->get()->map()`